# Does the domain name extension means the geographic location?

Tags: networking

Does the domain extension like `.us, .uk` means the geographic location of the server ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*Generally*, a website with a .us, .fr, or .ch domain means that a website is either hosted in/operates out of that country. This is not universal, however. Some countries will let you get a domain name of their country without actually being part of that country. The .tv code, for example, is the country code for the island nation of Tuvalu, but there are many sites from other countries that use that country code.

Answer (score 0):

Domain name does not indicate anything about the physical location of the server. It may for certain country codes, but a `.uk` domain for example can be registered by anyone without any geographic restrictions, let alone restrictions on where the server can be